# Go Api returning Unauthorized

Tags: reactjs, go

i am new learner of GoLang+React. So that i started a project to learn. I made a RESTful Api with GoLang. Api [Link](https://github.com/inadislam/go-todo-api.git). i made a login system with that api. And successfully i can login and set user data to sessionStorage. But the problem is when i am trying to logout a user by hit the logout endpoint of api with axios. First time it shows Unauthorized. and second time its showing Network Error.

Here is the Request code:

```
logout = () => {
    const user = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('userData'));
    const token = user.token;
    const uid = user.id;
    const url = "http://localhost:8000/logout"
    axios.post(url,{"user_id":uid},{"Authorization":`Bearer ${token}`}).then((response) => response.json()).then((result) => {
        let responseJson = result;
        console.log(responseJson);
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    })
}
```

Note: by client application i can logout successfully. But by axios i cant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide **auth headers** under `headers` property of Axios [config](https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config) object:

```
axios.post(
  url,
  { user_id: uid },
  { headers: { 'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}` } }
)
```

**Explanation:**

This is the axios post method signature, check [docs](https://github.com/axios/axios#axiosposturl-data-config):

```
axios.post(url[, data[, config]])
```

And the 3rd parameter [`config`](https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config) should have this interface:

```
{
  ...
  baseURL?: string;
  headers?: any; // this is for headers
  params?: any;
  ....
}
```

Comment: can you explain sir please because i am a New Learner

Comment: Thanks for explanation but i had added cors in my basicMiddleware and after your suggested question again i checked my cors and updated the middleware with that questions answer but still i am suffering that problem

Comment: Can you use capital case `B` for `Bearer XYZ_Your_Toke`  and retry?

Comment: First time i used Bearer and i got Error: Network Error and then i replaced it with bearer but unfortunately same thing. If you dont mind i gave a link of my api will you check out my middlewares and cors system? cors func is controller/controllers.go and routes in controllers folder. BTW bearer and Bearer both are working when i am sending request by client app. Response header is totally blank

Comment: I have already seen your files on github. CORS setting seems fine. I found [this](https://github.com/golang/oauth2/issues/113) about case sensitivity of `Bearer`.

Comment: Same sir i replaced bearer to Bearer but its showing same error

Answer (score 1):

I fixed that problem with adding this code to my package.json file

`"proxy":"http://localhost:your_port"`